# How to generalise hang picture puzzle?

Tags: puzzle-creation, topology

There is well known problem:

> The picture is attached to a string and you want to hang it on N nails so that if one takes out any of the nails, the picture falls. How do you do it?

*For those who have not heard this puzzle:

No brainteaser tricks are here, this is basically topology problem: "How to put N points and a closed curve on a plane in a way that curve can't be moved to infinity without crossing any point, but if one arbitrary point is removed - it can?"*

Is it possible to generalise in the following way?:

> The picture is attached to a string and you want to hang it on N nails so that if one takes out any M of the N nails, the picture falls, but if one takes out any M-1 nails the picture will not be freed. How do you do it?

Does this problem have a solution? Can it be shown that this is impossible to do if `M > 1`?

Comment: I believe it should be possible, but it gets exponentially harder as $M$ increases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a paper [available on the arXiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3602)* which investigates both the "remove one nail" variant (which they call "1-of-$n$") and a more generalized "$k$-of-$n$" version (remove $k$ out of $n$ nails to make the picture fall).

Theorem 1, on page 18 addresses the $1$-of-$n$ version:

> **Theorem 1** For any $n \geq 1$, there is a picture hanging on $n$ nails of length at most $2n^2$ that falls upon the removal of any one nail. For each $i = 1, 2, ..., n$, symbols $x_i$ and $x_i^{-1}$ appear at most $2n$ times.

I'm not going to reproduce the whole proof here, because it involves more LaTeX than I want to try and transcribe, but the gist of it (if I'm understanding it correctly) is:

1. We have $n = 1$ and $n = 2$ solutions.
2. We can show that any problem's solution is equivalent to splitting the problem in half and solving each half, then looping them together.
3. All problems can be recursively reduced to a series of $n =1$ or $n = 2$ problems.

<sub>* Paper source: [arXiv:1203.3602v2 [cs.DS] 26 Apr 2014](http://arxiv.org/abs/1203.3602)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, that is interesting. If you don't mind, please check my solution, does it looks correct for you?

Comment: Actually, now you was half an hour faster:)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can.

1. First, let's reformulate the puzzle to mathematical language.

   1. We place all nails on one straight line L and take some point P, far away from line L and all nails on it.
   2. We number all nails from 1 to N.
   3. We take the string; place one end at P; move the other end around some nail number X clockwise; move the end back to point P. Let's note all this operations as `O(X)`. Let's note the same operation, but done anticlockwise as `O*(X)`.
   4. Let's note several operations, which are done one after another (with nails A, B, ..., Z) as `O(A)O(B)..O(Z)`.
   5. If `S = O(A)O(B)..O(Z)`, let's denote `S* = O*(Z)..O*(B)O*(A)`.
   6. Let's note operator, which does nothing as `E`.
   7. Now our task is reformulated like this: find sequence of operators, which is not `E` when you remove any M-1 nails, and is `E` when you remove M nails.
2. Second, let's investigate properties of the operator `O(...)` and it's combinations `U`.

   1. `E = E*`.
   2. `O**(X) = O(X)`.
   3. If we take some nail X out then `O(X) will become E`. In sequence of operations we should remove all O(X) and O*(X). Since topologically these operations will do nothing.
   4. `O(X)O*(X) = E`. If in sequence of operations we have `O(X)O*(X)` we can remove it. Since topologically these operations will do nothing.
   5. `UU* = E`.
3. Then, let's solve the puzzle for M = 1.

   1. Let's note the sequence of operations, that solves the task for N nails 1,2,..,N as `F(1,2,..,N)`.
   2. If N = 1. Trivial solution is `F(1) = O(1)`.
   3. If N = K+1. Suppose that we solved N = K already (we can do it similarly to mathematical induction method). Solution is defined recursively from solution for K nails: `F(1,..,K,K+1) = F(1,...,K)O(K+1)F*(1,...,K)O*(K+1)`. This works because if you take one nail X <= K out `F(1,...,K) will become E` and `F(1,..,K,K+1) will became O(K+1)O*(K+1) = E`, if you take nail K+1 out `O(K+1) will become E`  and `F(1,..,K,K+1) will became F(1,..,K)F*(1,..,K) = E`.
   4. For example, solution for 3 nails is: `F(1,2,3) = O(1)O(2)O*(1)O*(2)O(3)O(2)O(1)O*(2)O*(1)O*(3)`.
4. Now, M > 1.

   1. Let's note the sequence of operations, that solves the task with N and M as `S(N,M)`.
   2. Let's invent sequence `G(X1,X2,..,XM)`, which is not `E` until you remove all nails among `X1,X2,..,XM`. It is quite trivial: `G(X1,X2,..,XM) = O(X1)O(X2)..O(XM)` - we just must hang the picture on all nails as one.
   3. Let's consider all possible combinations of M nails out of N: `1,2,..,M-1,M; 1,2,..,M-1,M+1; ... N-M+1,N-M+2,..,N-1,N`; Let's number them and call them `C1,C2,..,CR`, where `R = N choose M`. For each combination we can consider operator G: `G(Ck)`.
   4. Now we need to do the same procedure as we did with M=1, but instead of nails use combinations of nails. The solution is given recursively, in R steps: `S'(1,M) = G(C1); S'(k+1,M)=S'(k,M)G(Ck)S'*(k,M)G*(Ck)`, here k is number of k-th combination, `S'(k,M)` the sequience, which solves the task for first k combinations. Therefore `S'(k,M)` will work when you remove groups of nails, which belong to any combinations from 1 to k.
   5. The required solution is `S(K,M) = S'(N choose M,M)`. Indeed, if we remove one nail, neither combination from `Ck` will not become `E`, therefore `S(K,M)` will not become `E` and the picture will not be freed. If we remove any M nail, the removed nails are compose one combination from `Ck`, then `S(K,M) will become E` and the picture will fall.
   6. For example, solution for N=3, M=2 is: `S(3,2) = G(C1)G(C2)G*(C1)G*(C2)G(C3)G(C2)G(C1)G*(C2)G*(C1)G*(C3) = O(2)O(3)O(3)O(1)O*(3)O*(2)O*(1)O*(3)O(1)O(2)O(3)O(1)O(2)O(3)O*(3)O*(1)O*(3)O*(2)O*(2)O*(1)`.

Comment: `This works because if you take one nail X <= K out F(1,...,K) will become E` ->  Why is this true?  I would only expect O(X) to become E.  Please elaborate.  Other than that, it does seem to match the algorithm and results in the paper I linked.  Good writeup.

Comment: @Bobson, this works by definition of F(1,...,K). Thank you for checking.